# Using a voltage divider to measure output of generator, and use an Arduino to measure wind speed

Tags: circuit-design, generator, arduino-uno, windturbine

I am currently part of a group project in which we are required to build a turbine and generator that will turn on a light at a wind speed of 10 m/s.

How will I use the fluctuating voltage out of the generator, and by using an Arduino Uno (5 V) be able to measure the wind speed from the voltage generated, and at 10 m/s turn on the light bulb (6 V, 200 mA)?

Should I use a voltage divider? The voltage generated will be greater than 5 V, but no higher than 30 V.

Comment: Can the voltage produced be negative? Or will it always be a positive DC voltage? Even if it's nominally always positive, depending on how exactly the voltage is produced, it may be a good idea to put some kind of reverse polarity protection to avoid damage to the ADC.

Comment: Is the voltage of the generator a function of the wind speed? Is there a load to that voltage and does the voltage depend on load current?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a voltage divider. The Arduino Uno has a 10-bit ADC with 0-5V input.

So if you use a voltage divider like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQL2VO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This gives a full-scale reading for 30V in.

Comment: Thank you so much